# R - partitionsSample - Error message saying n exceeds the maximum number of possible results

Tags: r, random, partitioning, sampling

I am trying to split a number X into a defined number of random values so that the sum of this set of randomly generated values is X; this is done under the rule that none of the randomly generated values is greater than another value Y.
For example number 6 partitioned in 3 random values none of them greater than 4 (e.g. a possible results could either be 4,1,1 or 2,3,1 or 2,2,2)

For this I am using the partitionsSample function of the library `RcppAlgos`.
I have noticed that under some combinations, the function gives an error for example this works fine:

```
library(RcppAlgos)
goal <- 6
nPartitions <-3
MaxValue <- 4
m <- partitionsSample(v = MaxValue, m = nPartitions, repetition = TRUE, target = goal, n = 1)
m
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    4
```

but if I change the goal from 6 to 7 I get an error message:

```
goal <- 7
nPartitions <-3
MaxValue <- 4
m <- partitionsSample(v = MaxValue, m = nPartitions, repetition = TRUE, target = goal, n = 1)
Error: n exceeds the maximum number of possible results
```

that I can't understand because unless I am missing something, there should be valid solutions here, for example: (1,2,4) or (2,2,3) or (3,3,1)

Any help in understanding what is going on is highly appreciated!!

Comment: `RcppAlgos` author here. This a bug. I’m filing an issue and will report it back here when it’s done. The problem is arising because there are certain cases where determining the number of results is quite difficult and is skipped in the general case because we can simply rely on quickly generating the next partition efficiently until there are no more possibilities. The fix is quite simple and will be present in the next release, hopefully the end of this month.

Comment: hello Joseph, thanks for your reply and for working towards fixing the bug :) I suspected the origin of the problem was around that because when trying to achieve the same trough a loop, it took plenty of time. If you can solve it that would be fantastic as that function is hugely time-saving!!

Comment: I've just merged a fix to main. The CRAN team is on vacation right now, so pushing this to production will have to wait until they return (after August 5th). For now, one can get these changes via `devtools::install_github("jwood000/RcppAlgos")`.

Comment: great thanks for the update Joseph!

Comment: Btw, this is now in production on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppAlgos/news.html See the comments under `Bug Fixes` for version `2.5.5`.